# Storing a QTMovie file to launch on Startup of App

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

I'm trying to build a simple app for OSX using cocoa and the Qtkit. I would like to have a movie start playing as soon as the app is launched. I've created an app to play which can play  a .mov file on my located on my desktop, by referencing the location of the file.

I would of course like to store the .mov file within the app itself, so that it will play the specific file when the user launches the app, but I am not sure where or how to store it. Should I use the Core Data library? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There might be a reason to store a movie in a Core Data store, but this isn't it.

Store the movie file within your application's bundle, and use NSBundle or CFBundle to retrieve the URL to it to pass to QTKit.